# Conditional proxy re-direction in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, networking, proxy, eclipse-plugin

I am testing out an environment where I have multiple proxies set up depending on what URL I access. I have my browsers working by configuring my `wpad.dat` file properly according to the examples I found [here](http://findproxyforurl.com/pac_file_examples.html). However, I am using Eclipse 3.6 and cannot seem to find a way to access different proxies based on *any* conditional information.

Any Eclipse veterans have an idea? Is there a plugin that I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, folks, there is no way to do this. I ended running an instance of Apache on my local machine, and using it as a proxy to do the conditional redirection based on the domain using the `ProxyRemote` configuration. Read more about it here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote